# How to get the caller of a method in a decorator, in python?

Tags: python, decorator

Here is what I need to do:

```
def my_decorator():
    # Here I need to get the caller of my_method, in this case: "caller_class"

class caller_class():
    def __init__(self):
        p = test_class()
        p.my_method()

class test_class():
    @my_decorator
    def my_method(self):
        pass
```

Does anyone know how I should do this?

Comment: Pass in a reference to it in the method call itself. What you're asking for generally isn't possible.

Comment: I don't want to pass a reference. I thought the same, but I hoped there could be an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. Here it goes:

```
def my_decorator(f):
    def inner_func(calling_obj, *args, **kwargs):
        stack = inspect.stack()
        caller_obj = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"]
        # caller_obj is the caller of my_method
        return f(calling_obj, *args, **kwargs)            
    return inner_func

class caller_class():
    def __init__(self):
        p = test_class()
        p.my_method()

class test_class():
    @my_decorator
    def my_method(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you properly, the method has access to the instance that is calling the method. For example:

```
In [2]: def a_decorator(f):      
            def inner_func(calling_obj, *args, **kwargs):
                print calling_obj # the instance will be the first argument
                return f(calling_obj, *args, **kwargs)            
            return inner_func

In [3]: class AClass(object):
   ...:     @a_decorator
   ...:     def a_method(self, stuff):
   ...:         return stuff + 1
In [4]: obj = AClass()

In [5]: obj.a_method(2)
<__main__.AClass object at 0x104870750>
Out[5]: 3
```

If you want to do something with the calling instance, you can do it right where I put the print statement.

Comment: Just a small thing:  this assumes that the decorator is only used on a method.  If used on a regular function then `calling_obj` might not be there.  I suggest using `args[0]` instead with the condition `if args and hasattr(args[0], '__class__'):`

Comment: That will give me access to my_method, but I need access to caller of my_method. Thanks.